# To execute AsyncTask from onClick(DialogInterface dialog)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Currently I have two java class, 1 with AsyncTask and another one is with extend DialogFragment.

I would like to call CreateGroupTask(AsyncTask) in ChooseAddContact java class.
I have tried several recommended ways to execute the AsyncTask java but all failed. 
Any recommendation or solution to that?

```
public class ChooseAddContact extends DialogFragment  {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_add)
           .setItems(R.array.contact_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               if (which == 0){
                   AddContactDialog dialog2 = new AddContactDialog();
                dialog2.show(getFragmentManager(), "AddContactDialog");
               } else if (which == 1){

                   **How should I CALL it here??
                   //new CreateGroupTask().execute();

                   //makegroup = new CreateGroupTask();
                   //makegroup.execute();                      
               }**                 
           }
    });
    return builder.create();    }
```

}

And

```
public class CreateGroupTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

private Context mContext;
private ProgressDialog pd;

public CreateGroupTask() {

}
public CreateGroupTask(Context mContext) {
    super();
    this.mContext = mContext; 
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, null, "Creating group...");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String chatId = ServerUtilities.create();
    if (chatId == null) return null;

    try {
        ...
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {}

    return chatId;
}   

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    pd.dismiss();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    pd.dismiss();

    if (result != null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Group created " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Group creation failed. Please retry later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why did you fail..?? what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: are you still facing problem? no any answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

In Dialog Fragment

To Start the async task you need context. In dialog Fragment you can get the context by calling `getActivity()`; or else you can get the `context or activity` reference in `onAttach()` lifecycle method of dialog fragment. Already parametrized constructor is  there better to remove zero parametrized constructor.

```
new CreateGroupTask(getActivity()).execute();

      (OR)

private Activity activity;

onAttach(Activity activity){
this.activity=activity;
   //store this activity reference
}

//Then Call
new CreateGroupTask(activity).execute();
```

Comment: Your answer appeared in the low quality review queue. Please edit your post to include a description why this solves the problem.

Comment: thanks and i got the idea about context now... problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing in AsyncTask is **Context**. you are using *mContext* in below code

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, null, "Creating group...");
```

but you are not initializing that object in default constructor.

Use **getActivity** while calling task

```
new CreateGroupTask(getActivity()).execute();
```

Also remove following constructor from your code

```
public CreateGroupTask() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of the class CreateGroupTask and execute wherever you want.

`CreateGroupTask createGroupTask = new CreateGroupTask();`

then

`                                                                                                                                   if (which == 0){ AddContactDialog dialog2 = new AddContactDialog();

```
           dialog2.show(getFragmentManager(), "AddContactDialog");
           } else if (which == 1){

               createGroupTask.execute(); 
                // Or new CreateGroupTask().execute();
           }`
```

try this and tell us if any error

Comment: yes i have tried that before and it hits nullpointerexception